# Checking input list size using camel DSL/spring config xml

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, fuseesb

Calling db to get ids' of an entity.  I am receiving list of entities. After getting ids list I need to call a webservice by passing that entities list. If the size of the list is more than 100, I should make multiple calls as the webservice will not accept more than hundred id's with a list.

Help me with the camel dsl in spring xml format to control the input and to pass the same controlled input to the webservice.

I have created context as below.but stuck with splitting or partition the webservice requests if the input list size is more than 100.

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="aisEndPoint"  
       address="/WebService"
          endpointName="a:DPWVessel"
          serviceName="a:VesselService" 
          wsdlURL="ScheduleWebService.wsdl"
          serviceClass="cargo.DPWVessel" />
<camelContext id="AIS-Integration"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">



<route id="getAISVesselDetails">
                <from
                    uri="quartz://aisVesselUpdates?cron={{ais.integration.vessels.timer}}" />
                <doTry>
                    <to uri="mybatisPromis:getVessels?statementType=SelectList" />
                    <to uri="bean:aisIntegrationProcessor?method=createInputForAISService" />
                    <to uri="cxf:bean:aisEndPoint" /> 
                    <doCatch>
                        <exception>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception>
                    </doCatch>
                    <doFinally>
                        <to uri="log:body" />
                    </doFinally>
                </doTry>
            </route>
        </camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the list in chunks of 100. Use camel loop and a processor.

Loop : every iteration takes 100 elements of the list until the listsize has been reached

Processor : take out required no of list values into a new list, pass new list to your webservice having 100 elements in each iteration.